# The getContextPath() is behaving differently in different environment

Tags: java, apache, http, jsp, jboss6.x

In our Jboss application the getContextPath() is behaving differently in different environment. Request.getContextPath() is returning the https://[servername]/contextPath instead of https://[loadbalncer-url]/contextPath. Here are the details

Webserver: Apache Tomcat 7 for loadbalancing
Application Server : JBOSS 6.2

**In Development Environment:**

*Loadbalncer-url* :  https://esam-dev.abc.com

*Application server*: c1234.abc.com

**In Testing Environment:**

*Loadbalncer-url* :  https://esam-test.abc.com

*Application server*: c5678.abc.com

*Context Path*: /emea

The application is using struts and jsp. In one of the jsp pages we are using

```
<link type="text/css" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/sca/UISfdc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In the Testing environment the above href is evaluating to

```
https://esam-test.abc.com/emea//sca/UISfdc.css
```

However in Development environment it is getting evaluated to

```
https://c5678.abc.com/emea/sca/UISfdc.css instead of https://esam-dev.abc.com/emea/sca/UISfdc.css
```

We are not able figure out why? Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think you should check the difference between the two environments when you deploy your server. This maybe due to there was a variable  put in wrong position. Can you swap the value of Loadbalncer-url and Application server in Developement Environment to see if the getContextPath() return exactly what you want?

Comment: Those two are not variables. load balancer url  is the one which is used for accessing the application. The application server is where the JBOSS application is running. The calls from the loadbalancer urls get diverted to application sevrer  through apache proxy

Comment: This issue got resolved. It was a configuration issue. The application is using struts with sca and wpa. In the sca configuration (sca-config.xml) wrong hostnmame had been configured (it was pointing to server name). After changing that value to loadbalncer it started working. So this issue may be closed